# jar doesn´t see the config.properties?

Tags: java, jar

I have a project with the this structure:

```
myPoject
    src
        com.config
           PropertiesFile.java
        com.main
           Main.java
    resources
        data.png
    config.properties


public class PropertiesFile {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PropertiesFile.class);

    private static final char CONFIG_DELIMITER = ',';
    private static final String CONFIG = "config.properties";

    private static org.apache.commons.configuration2.Configuration config;

    static {
        try {
            Parameters params = new Parameters();
            FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> builder = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
                .configure(params.properties()
                    .setFileName(CONFIG)
                    .setListDelimiterHandler(new DefaultListDelimiterHandler(CONFIG_DELIMITER)));

            config = builder.getConfiguration();    } 
        catch (ConfigurationException cE) {     
            logger.fatal("Error", cE);
        }
    }

    public static final String ID    = config.getString("id");
    public static final String DEST_HOST    = config.getString("destination.host");
    public static final int  DEST_PORT = config.getInt("destination.port");     
}
```

config.properties

```
id                      = myApp
destination.host        = localhost
destination.port        = 9898
```

Main.java

```
public class Main{  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {            
        Thread tc = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                connect();  
            }           
        });

        tc.start();     
        tc.join();
    }


    private static void connect() {

        try (Socket socket = new Socket(PropertiesFile.DEST_HOST, PropertiesFile.DEST_PORT)) {      

            //...code           

    }
}
```

When I runnit in eclipse it works fine but when I make the jar and try to execute I get this error

ago 28, 2018 10:23:28 AM org.apache.commons.beanutils.FluentPropertyBeanIntrospector introspect
INFORMACIËN: Error when creating PropertyDescriptor for public final void org.apache.commons.config
uration2.AbstractConfiguration.setProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)! Ignoring this property.
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.main.Main.connect(Main.java:47)
at com.main.Main.access$0(Main.java:46)
at com.main.Main$1.run(Main.java:37)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Key 'destination.port' does not map to an existing object!
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.throwMissingPropertyException(AbstractConfiguration.java:1911)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.checkNonNullValue(AbstractConfiguration.java:1898)
t org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.getInt(AbstractConfiguration.java:1262)
at com.config.PropertiesFile.(PropertiesFile.java:43)
... 5 more

Is the jar not seeing the config.properties file?

Comment: File `config.properties` should be under `resources` folder

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: No clue what a `FileBasedConfigurationBuilder` is. Is there a missing tag for a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File `config.properties` should be under resource folder.